# XDP program ipheader, data, nh_off confusion

Tags: bpf, ebpf

I'm studying XDP codes right now and I'm having some confusion as regards to how programs approach certain parts of a packet header.
So! When I look at the code that gets the IP address of a packet, it goes like:

```c
static inline int parse_ipv4(void *data, u64 nh_off, void *data_end) {
struct iphdr *iph = data + nh_off;

if ((void*)&iph[1] > data_end)
    return 0;
    return iph->protocol;
}
```

Now here are some things that confuse me :

```c
struct iphdr *iph = data + nh_off;
```

1. I thought `nh_off` is the offset value to the next header, so if you add `data + nh_off`, shouldn't that take you to the next packet? 
   Because to my understanding, if you add next header offset to the data, there should be a next packet waiting to be processed!
2. What does

   `(void*)&iph[1]`

   do exactly? I tried to guess what this line of code does for a few days but I still have no clue at all.

I am so sorry if my questions are too absorb or vague.. This things have been bothering me for a while and I would greatly appreciate it if someone could share their knowledge with me. Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on your code, since I don't see how `nh_off` is defined in your case. But most of the time, it *does* point to the next header, so we would have:

1. `nh_off` being the offset of the *next header* after Ethernet header has been parsed, i.e. `nh_off` is the offset of the IP header in the packet (typically, it's set to 14 at this stage, the number of bytes in the Ethernet header if no VLAN/encap is used).

   Setting `struct iphdr *iph = data + nh_off;` declares and initialises `iph` as a `struct iphdr` pointer, so we can reuse it afterwards to easily reach each field from the IPv4 header. It points to `data + nh_off`, i.e. the beginning of the packet plus the offset at which the IPv4 header begins in the packet.

   Next packet to be processed is not accessible from within your eBPF program; you would get a new `ctx` with a `data` pointer pointing to it when *that* new packet is processed with a new call to the BPF program, but you only see just one packet at once.
2. So `iph` points to the beginning of your IPv4 header. We can use that pointer to easily reach the individual fields (e.g. `iph->protocol` to get L4 protocol). But before we do that we must ensure that the packet is long enough and actually contains those field. Otherwise we could do an out-of-bound access (therefore the verifier would reject the program in the first place). This is the check we do here: `if ((void*)&iph[1] > data_end) return 0;`

   In that verification, `(void*)&iph[1]` means: i) Consider a `struct iphdr *` array (`&iph`, a pointer to a pointer to a `struct iphdr`). ii) Take the second cell of that array, e.g. the address of the struct pointed by the second `struct iphdr *`, e.g. the address of the byte that starts right after the first `struct iphdr` in the packet. And iii) cast it as a `void *` so we can compare it with `data_end`. In other words, this is a way to compare `data_end` (the address in memory right after the last byte of the packet) and the address of the byte right after IPv4 header (so possibly first byte of L4 is packet is long enough). If `(void*)&iph[1]` is bigger than `data_end`, then the IPv4 header we considered is longer than the actual packet we got, and we cannot afford to dereference `iph` to try to reach e.g. the `protocol` field.

With a diagram, maybe:

```
Packet data

| Ethernet     | IPv4               | IPv4 data (e.g. L4, data)       |
+--------------+--------------------+------ ... ----------------------+
^              ^                    ^                                 ^
data           data + nh_off        |                                 data_end
               iph                  |
               &iph[0]              &iph[1]
```

We would have an issue to access `iph->protocol` if we had the following instead (this is why we `return 0` if the comparison succeeds):

```
Packet data

| Ethernet     | <something>   | End of packet
+--------------+----------------    +
^              ^               ^    ^
data           data + nh_off   |    |
               iph             |    |
               &iph[0]         |    &iph[1]
                               data_end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind explanation! It really helps me out a lot! I think I now finally understand what these codes mean :D